# javafx.scene.control.Dialog<R> won't close on pressing "x"

Tags: java, javafx, dialog

If I just create an empty class extending from `javafx.scene.control.Dialog<R>`, it won't close when I'm pressing the "x" button in the top right corner.

How do I implement this behaviour? The API seems to tell me that I need to implement a close button. But in my case I don't want a close button, I just want to close the window with the x button or by pressing ESC. Is this possible?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To work-around this, you could add a hidden close button to the dialog.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class DialogClosure extends Application{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Button openDialog = new Button("Open Dialog");
        openDialog.setOnAction(event -> {
            Dialog dialog = new Dialog();
            dialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().add(ButtonType.CLOSE);
            Node closeButton = dialog.getDialogPane().lookupButton(ButtonType.CLOSE);
            closeButton.managedProperty().bind(closeButton.visibleProperty());
            closeButton.setVisible(false);
            dialog.showAndWait();
        });

        stage.setScene(new Scene(openDialog));
        stage.show();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Then the dialog meets both your requirement of being able to be closed via the native windowing system's window close icon as well as the JavaFX Dialog requirement of including a close button in the dialog for the close icon to work.

Alternately, you could use a Stage with [showAndWait](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#showAndWait--) instead of a [Dialog](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Dialog.html).  A Stage without any included buttons is closable using the windowing system's close window icon.

Comment: Hiding 'Close' button appears to disable 'Esc' functionality.

Answer (score 27):

The workaround from @eckig or @jewelsea works pretty fine. But I would use something like this:

```
// Somewhere in code
Dialog<?> dialog = new Dialog<>();
Window    window = dialog.getDialogPane().getScene().getWindow();
window.setOnCloseRequest(event -> window.hide());
```

I do not know any constrains of this use, but it worked for me.
And I recommend initialize window right after dialog initialization, like above.

Answer (score 10):

To quote the [Api Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Dialog.html):

> JavaFX dialogs can only be closed 'abnormally' (as defined above) in
> two situations:
>
> 1. When the dialog only has one button, or
> 2. When the dialog has multiple buttons, as long as one of them meets one of the following requirements:
>
>    1. The button has a ButtonType whose ButtonData
>       is of type ButtonData.CANCEL_CLOSE.
>    2. The button has a ButtonType whose
>       ButtonData returns true when ButtonData.isCancelButton() is called.
>
>    ...

So either add at least one button or multiple buttons, and one of them is of type `ButtonData.CANCEL_CLOSE`, for example:

```
Dialog<ButtonType> dialog = new Dialog<>();
dialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().add(new ButtonType("Got it!", ButtonData.CANCEL_CLOSE));
dialog.setContentText("test");
dialog.showAndWait();
```

---

Edit:

This behavior is implemented in `javafx.scene.control.FXDialog.requestPermissionToClose(Dialog<?>)`, but the real `FXDialog` shown is `HeavyweightDialog` which is not public API so not really an extension point.

Comment: How does it make sense that you have to implement a close button to be able to use another close button? Why do you have to have both? Is there anything else that I can use if I need to return a result from the window without wanting any buttons (except those in the title bar, like "x"). Initially I created my own class from scratch to implement this behaviour, but I was unable to return a result.

Comment: @JonatanStenbacka Only solution would be to implement your own `FXDialog`.. but I would not recommend this. But I can not imagine a Dialog without any buttons...?

Comment: Confirming that this is the only working option i've seen. Awesome thanks.

Comment: The dialog shoud have at least 1 button "Ok" or "Got it!" like proposed by eckig. All is ok with only one, default button. But if you add at least a second button, the closing behavior is broken ... You have to redefine the default button to force it to be a "CANCEL_CLOSE" button. so call dialog.getDialogePane().getButtonTypes().addAll(new ButtonType("OK", ButtonData.CANCEL_CLOSE)); And all will be ok. Close button works, Esc key too.

Answer (score 1):

In my `Dialog<ButtonType>` I'm using what @vbargl said:

```
Window window = alert.getDialogPane().getScene().getWindow();
window.setOnCloseRequest(event -> window.hide());
```

It closes the dialog, but it's bringing me a *no value present* error.

To avoid it, I'm also checking `result.get()` and that `result.isPresent()`.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this situation with alerts with the below code.

```
Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.NONE);
     alert.setTitle("Export Successful");
     alert.setContentText("All the posts have been exported to Posts.txt file 
 successfully");
    alert.show();
```

The only workaround would be to create an alert or dialog with a button in it like below.

```
Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
    alert.setTitle("Export Successful");
    alert.setContentText("All the posts have been exported to Posts.txt file 
successfully");
    alert.showAndWait();
```