# JavaFX close Dialog without setting result

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I created a `Button` via FXML and associated an `onAction()` method

```
<Button fx:id="cancelButton" cancelButton="true" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#cancelButtonAction" text="Cancel" />
```

The Button should close a `Dialog` but since it's a cancel button I don't want to set a result.
My problem is that the dialog doesn't close if I don't set a result.

```
Dialog<String> dialog = new Dialog<>();

public void cancelButtonAction(){
    System.out.println("cancel"); // this get's called
    // dialog.setResult("foo");   // not working without this line
    dialog.close();               // does not close the dialog
}
```

How can I close the dialog without setting a result?

Comment: Is there a reason you create the button through FXML and not through `Dialog`'s `createButton`?  Have a look at "Dialog Closing Rules" in the end of the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Dialog.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely caused by the dialogue rules which are outlined here : [Dialogue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Dialog.html#initModality-javafx.stage.Modality-)

Specifically these rules:

> 1.
>   If a dialog is closed abnormally, and if the dialog contains a button
>   which meets one of the two criteria above, the dialog will attempt to
>   set the result property to whatever value is returned from calling the
>   result converter with the first matching ButtonType.
>
> 2.
>   If for any reason the result converter returns null, or if the dialog
>   is closed when only one non-cancel button is present, the result
>   property will be null, and the showAndWait() method will return
>   Optional.empty(). This later point means that, if you use either of
>   option 2 or option 3 (as presented earlier in this class
>   documentation), the Optional.ifPresent(java.util.function.Consumer)
>   lambda will never be called, and code will continue executing as if
>   the dialog had not returned any value at all.
>
> 3.
>   JavaFX dialogs can only be closed 'abnormally' (as defined above) in
>   two situations:
>   When the dialog only has one button, or When the dialog has multiple
>   buttons, as long as one of them meets one of the following
>   requirements:
>   The button has a ButtonType whose ButtonData is of type
>   ButtonData.CANCEL_CLOSE. The button has a ButtonType whose ButtonData
>   returns true when ButtonData.isCancelButton() is called.

Maybe try this if you just want to quickly fix the problem if its not critical :

```
dialog.setResult(null);
//Or this just to keep it simple
dialog.setResult("");
```

Mentioned on a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32048348/javafx-scene-control-dialogr-wont-close-on-pressing-x) It is possible to just add a cancel_close button to fix this :

```
dialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().add(new ButtonType("Cancel", ButtonData.CANCEL_CLOSE));
// or as jorn said you can simple do this :
dialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().add( ButtonType.CANCEL);
```

Here is a full example:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.scene.control.Dialog;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class JavaFXApplication2 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Button openDialog = new Button("Open Dialog");
        openDialog.setOnAction(event -> {
            Dialog dialog = new Dialog();
            dialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().add( ButtonType.CANCEL);
            dialog.setContentText("Example");
            dialog.showAndWait();
        });

        stage.setScene(new Scene(openDialog));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: For that last line, you could also use [```ButtonType.CANCEL```](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ButtonType.html#CANCEL).

Comment: Valid point :) i was just quoting from the other post i linked for das :)

Comment: Updated to include an example of @Jorn solution

Comment: Setting the result to null isn't working. But I'm currently considering another way, using a Stage instead of a dialog because I also have problems with the dialog size and closing via the X button. Besides that, thanks for posting the dialog rules. I don't read them yet

Comment: I think normally you can do something like : dialog.setResizable(true);
dialog.getDialogPane().setPrefSize(480, 320);
dialog.showAndWait(); However maybe using a stage maybe simpler, good luck das :)