# JavaFX - Any way to enter the JavaFX-Thread while executing a background task?

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, task

I have the following Task, where I import a file. The method starts a Dialog with a ProgressBar, and the progressProperty from the ProgressBar is bound to the progressProperty of the task. Now I want to check if the ProgressBar is already done, but I have to ProgressBar in a special class and I can't access methods from any other classes while executing the Task. Now, my question is, how can I ensure that the program checks if the ProgressBar is done, because my Dialog will only close if the ProgressBar is finished, and at the current moment, the Dialog never closes. Here is my code:

```
public void readFile(File chat) {
    Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {

        @Override
        protected Void call() throws Exception {
            if(chat.getName().contains("KakaoTalk_")) {
                String s = "";
                String gesamt = "";
                double laenge = 0;
                try(BufferedReader brCount = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(chat))) {
                    while((s=brCount.readLine())!=null) {
                        laenge++;
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("Fehler beim zählen");
                }
                double momentanErreicht = 0;
                try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(chat))) {
                    while((s=br.readLine())!=null) {
                        momentanErreicht++;
                        updateProgress(momentanErreicht, laenge);
                        s = s.replace("ÃŸ", "ß");
                        s = s.replace("Ã¶", "ö");
                        s = s.replace("Ã¼", "ü");
                        s = s.replace("Ã¤", "ä");
                        s = s.replace("Ã„", "Ä");
                        s = s.replace("Ãœ", "Ü");
                        s = s.replace("Ã–", "Ö");
                        gesamt += s+"\n";
                    }
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                    System.out.println("File not found");
                } catch (IOException e2) {
                    System.out.println("IOException");
                }
                mp.isFortschrittDialogCompleted();
                mp.eingabeSetText(gesamt);
                setChat(mp.eingabeGetText());
                getChat();
            } else mp.mhNichtPassendesFile();
            return null;
        }
    };
    mp.progressP().bind(task.progressProperty());
    mp.startFortschrittDialog();
    Thread th = new Thread(task);
    th.setDaemon(true);
    th.start();
    mp.isFortschrittDialogCompleted();
}
```

Here is also my MyRootPane (mp) where the executed methods lead to:

```
    public void eingabeSetText(String eingabe) {
        this.eingabe.setText(eingabe);
    }
    public String eingabeGetText() {
        return eingabe.getText();
    }
    public void startFortschrittDialog() {
        fd.show();
    }
    public void endFortschrittDialog() {
        fd.close();
    }
    public void isFortschrittDialogCompleted() {
        if(fd.isCompleted()) endFortschrittDialog();
    }
    public DoubleProperty progressP() {
        return fd.getPBProgressProperty();
    }
```

And the Dialog with the ProgressBar:

```
public class FortschrittDialog extends Dialog {

    private ProgressBar pb = new ProgressBar();

    public FortschrittDialog() {
        pb.setPrefWidth(500);
        pb.setProgress(-1f);

        getDialogPane().setContent(pb);
    }
    public DoubleProperty getPBProgressProperty() {
        return pb.progressProperty();
    }
    public boolean isCompleted() {
        if(pb.getProgress()==1.0) return true;
        else return false;
    }
}
```

I hope anyone understands my problem and can give me a quick and easy solutions, if possible even with explanation. If your missing something of the code, please tell

Comment: I didn't read your code but do you mean the UI thread? Does [`Platform.runLater`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater-java.lang.Runnable-) work?

Comment: Well, yes I'm talking of the UI thread (at least, that's what I think what I'm talking of...)
I'm not quite sure how I use this Platform.runLater, but when I try (like: Platform.runLater(mp.isFortschrittDialogCompleted();) it tells me that I would have to change the return type from boolean to Runnable.

Comment: You can do this: `Platform.runLater(() -> mp.isFortschrittDialogCompleted())` but you won't get the boolean return value back. It doesn't look like you currently use that value, so it should be okay.

Comment: So, I just noticed that I don't even have a return type on this method, so now I wonder even more why I would have to change the return type...

Comment: You're calling `mp.isFortschrittDialogCompleted()` immediately after starting the task: clearly the task won't be completed at that point. The approach just seems wrong: instead of using the progress property, just register an `onSucceeded` handler with the task, and close the dialog from there. If I understand your code correctly, you just need `task.setOnSucceeded(e -> mp.endFortschrittDialog());`.

Comment: Why should the background task ask the UI whether it has been completed? Besides that, if you want to read an `UTF-8` file, you should just read the file using the `UTF-8` encoding instead of reading it with the wrong encoding and doing this string replacement. E.g. `java.nio.file.Files.readAllLines(chat.toPath())` reads all lines into a `List<String>` and even uses the `UTF-8` encoding by default (but you can specify another encoding as second parameter).

Comment: Thank you James_D, this sounds indeed like a good idea, but as I just found out while debugging, the Dialog does not close with `fd.close();`, and I don't know why, I'm currently trying to find out.
Also, thank you Holger, I see what you mean, but I don't quite know how to realise this with my current code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to one of this [javafx.scene.control.Dialog<R> won't close on pressing "x"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32048348/javafx-scene-control-dialogr-wont-close-on-pressing-x) question's answer, you can only close the dialog if you have a defined button on your dialog pane, then you can do somethig like this:

```
    Window window = dialog.getDialogPane().getScene().getWindow();
    window.setOnCloseRequest(event -> dialog.close());
```

Then as @James_D mentioned in a comment you can use

```
    task.setOnSucceeded(event -> window.hide());
```

this is the relevant part for you from the answer:

> JavaFX dialogs can only be closed 'abnormally' (as defined above) in
>   two situations:
>
> - When the dialog only has one button,
> - When the dialog has multiple
>     buttons, as long as one of them meets one of the following
>     requirements:
>
>   - The button has a ButtonType whose ButtonData is of type
>       ButtonData.CANCEL_CLOSE.
>   - The button has a ButtonType whose ButtonData
>       returns true when ButtonData.isCancelButton() is called. ...

If you are using this solution you don't have to use the `doubleProperty` and the `isCompleted()` methods.

Comment: Thank you, I just read about the problem with closing Dialogs too. :D
It seems to work now, thanks for the help. ^^